# ¿Cómo saber el color de un box-shadow?

Tags: javascript, css

Tengo una serie de imágenes que se cargan con un borde amarillo `box-shadow:#FF9 10px 10px 15px;`.
Al hacer clic en cualquiera de ellas cambia el color del borde a negro.
Si pulso en una de color negro, vuelve a cambiar el color del borde a amarillo:

```
var foto=document.querySelectorAll("figure");
for (var i=0;i<foto.length;i++){
    foto[i].addEventListener("click",cambia_color,false);
}
function cambia_color(e){
    var dimecolor=$(e.target).css("box-shadow");
    if (dimecolor=="rgb(255, 255, 153) 10px 10px 15px 0px"){
    var color=$(e.target).css({"box-shadow":"#666 10px 10px 15px 0px","background":"#000"});
    }else
        if(dimecolor=="rgb(102, 102, 102) 10px 10px 15px 0px"){
            var color=$(e.target).css({"box-shadow":"#FF9 10px 10px 15px 0px","background":"#FF0"});
    }
}
```

Lo que necesito es que al pulsar en un icono (id=imagen8) elimine las de color amarillo.
Para ello hago lo siguiente:

```
document.getElementById("Image8").addEventListener("click",borra_seleccion,false);
function borra_seleccion(e){
    var foto=document.querySelectorAll("figure");
    var Total=foto.length;
    for (var i=0;i<Total;i++){
        var color =$(this).css("box-shadow"); // No funciona
        alert(color);
    }
}
```

El bucle `for (var i=0;i<Total;i++)` funciona bien, pero `var color =$(this).css("box-shadow");` no funciona.

Necesito saber cómo puedo detectar el color en el bucle para borrar las de color amarillo.

Answer (score 1):

Para lograr lo que quieres, es mucho más simple tener dos clases separadas. No solo puedes manejar más fácilmente el "cambio de color", sino también la eliminación de los elementos, he preparado un ejemplo con dos clases (`.seleccionado` y `.normal`). Los elementos seleccionados tienen el fondo amarillo y los *normales* el fondo negro.

Cuando se hace clic en el elemento `<figure>`, haciendo `toggle` de ambas clases se quita la que tenía y se le deja puesta la otra, con lo que cambia entre amarillo (seleccionado) y negro (normal).

El botón busca todos los elementos seleccionados y los elimina del DOM.

Puedes probar la funcionalidad aquí mismo haciendo clic en el botón **Ejecutar**, al final del *snippet* de código.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var foto=document.querySelectorAll("figure");
  for (var i=0;i<foto.length;i++){
      foto[i].addEventListener("click",cambia_color,false);
  }
});

function cambia_color(e){
  let laFigura;
  if (e.target.nodeName == 'FIGURE') laFigura = e.target
  else if (e.target.parentNode && e.target.parentNode.nodeName == 'FIGURE')  laFigura = e.target.parentNode;
  
  if (laFigura) {
    $(laFigura).toggleClass("seleccionado");
    $(laFigura).toggleClass("normal");
  }
}

function borrarSeleccion() {
  $(".seleccionado").remove();
}
```

```css
figure {
  margin: 10px;
  padding: 10px;
  width: 170px;
  float: left;
  text-align: center;
}


figcaption {
  background: gray;
}

figure.seleccionado {
  box-shadow: #FF9 10px 10px 15px 0px;
  background: #FF0;
}

figure.normal {
  box-shadow: #666 10px 10px 15px 0px;
  background: #000;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="div">
  <figure id="fig1" class="seleccionado">
    <img src="https://www.gravatar.com/avatar/101970df46cc6f3ba9a83daae9b54613?s=150&d=identicon&r=PG">
    <figcaption>jachguate</figcaption>
  </figure>
  <figure id="fig2" class="seleccionado">
    <img src="https://www.gravatar.com/avatar/b66cdef56ab88b2a8ff1eeb7b5c503c7?s=150&d=identicon&r=PG">
    <figcaption>Carlos del juez</figcaption>
  </figure>
  <figure id="fig3" class="seleccionado">
    <img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/7UmHim.jpg?s=150&g=1" width="150">
    <figcaption>anythingg</figcaption>
  </figure>
  <figure id="fig4" class="seleccionado">
    <img src="https://www.gravatar.com/avatar/205e460b479e2e5b48aec07710c08d50?s=150&d=identicon&r=PG">
    <figcaption>otra persona</figcaption>
  </figure>
  <button id="boton" onclick="borrarSeleccion()">Borrar amarillos</button>
</div>
```

Ojo, que para cambiar el color debes hacer clic a la izquierda o derecha de la foto.

### Edición

En una versión anterior de esta respuesta había un bug, ya que el método `cambia_color` se disparaba cuando se hacía clic, no solo sobre la *figura*, sino sobre sus elementos hijos, e incorrectamente se cambiaba la clase de estos (de la imagen y/o de su etiqueta).

Esto provocaba que, al borrar, ya que solo nos basamos en la clase, se borraran algunos de estos elementos, que estaban en *figuras* que no se borraban y quedaban incompletas.

En esta versión, se inspecciona el tipo de elemento de `e.target` y, si no es `'FIGURE'`, se *mira hacia arriba*, para ver si el padre lo es.

Al final, solamente si se ha encontrado la figura se hace el cambio de clase. Con ello nos aseguramos que solo se borren *figuras completas* y nunca sus elementos, pues solo estas podrán tener la clase `.seleccionado`.

Comment: Muchas gracias por tu respuesta, una solución muy inteligente.
Un saludo

Comment: Hola @jachguate
La respuesta  es muy buena, pero se me plantea un problema y es cómo puedo hacer que no se eliminen los nombres de las personas seleccionas.
Hacer que se mantenga la imagen y su nombre. Si observáis en al ejemplo, al eliminar alguna imagen, elimina también los nombres de las no seleccionadas.
Un saludo.

Comment: No entiendo bien a lo que te refieres. ¿Para comenzar, mi ejemplo o tu ejemplo? ¿Qué es exactamente lo que hace de más o de menos?

Comment: Si te fijas bien en tu ejemplo cuando eliminas una o varias imágenes, las que quedan aparecen sin el nombre de usuario "figcaption" también se borra. Un saludo

Comment: No se borran, cambié el color de fondo de los `<figcaption>`s para que puedas verlos aún cuando estén _no seleccionadas_ las imágenes.

Comment: ¿Cómo puedo hacer para que una vez que le doy al botón “borrar amarillos” las imágenes que me queden aparezcan con su nombre debajo?
Un saludo

Comment: No hay que hacer nada: https://imgur.com/a/6evnfyZ Simplemente, están allí.

Comment: Vale, ya lo pillé.
Tengo un pequeño problema y es que cuando hago clic encima de una foto que quiero mantener visible ósea las negras, al mandarle borrar las seleccionadas, me borra la foto, pero mantiene el nombre. Esto también pasa en tu ejemplo. 
Primero haces clic en el marco, cambia a negro, después haces clic encima de la imagen de ese marco, sigue de color negro y posteriormente haces clic en el botón de eliminar. Puedes ver que elimina la imagen y mantiene el nombre.
Si se te ocurre algo para evitarlo te estaré agradecido
Por lo demás todo correcto.
Un saludo.

Comment: ha, un bug! Edité la respuesta, corregí el código y dejé, al final, una explicación de lo que pasaba, que era muy larga para un comentario. Buen catch y, al final, buen reporte de error. No olvides aceptar la respuesta, después de tanto esfuerzo, sería una lástima que no lo hicieras ;-)

Comment: Ahora todo perfecto.
Un saludo.

Comment: Me alegra ser de ayuda. Considera marcar la respuesta como aceptada, pues esto ayudará en el futuro a quienes lleguen aquí a identificar que la respuesta **si** fue de ayuda. Recuerda que en StackOverflow puedes saber, de esta manera, si hubo una respuesta útil y cuál es. Es muy útil cuando llegas aquí googlando un proximo problema. Esto no resta mérito a otras respuestas y en ocasiones habrá buenas o hasta mejores respuestas no aceptadas, pero si que ayuda. Si no sabes como aceptar una respuesta, haz el [tour].